# How to debug application directly on windows mobile?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, testing, windows-mobile

I am developing a windows mobile application in which I want to debug the application not on the simulator but on the phone directly

So is there any way to do this?

I am currently connecting the device to visual studio after syncing it and have added a custom certificate too. But when I start the debugging the debugging stops at "Application.Run()" and then nothing happens.

If their is a step by step tutorial available it would be of great help.

Comment: while waiting for a solution, you can always rely on the age old method of printing to logfiles. Although hardly a substitute for a debugger, a few quick prints can do wonders. ;^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys I got it. Was doing a silly mistake. I had set the target platform as "Windows mobile 6.0 professional sdk" but i was using a phone which was a 6.0 standard device. Sorry for bothering you people